# Reproduce triple tunnel in a single ssh line

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to reproduce this in a single SSH line?

What I'm doing is:

1. Connecting to 12.12.12.123 with root and mapping 5432 to 5001
2. From there, I connect to 22.22.222.22 and map its 5432 to  12.12.12.123:5432

Here's a picture
[image]